# Android: How to design the ListView xml

Tags: android, xml

I am making a contacts app. I wish to list the contact name one after another. However, the result that I get is not satisfactory. The output of this xml is contact name was listed in a way that one contact name for each background. I have a very long space between each contact name.

Below is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/contactTextView" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The output looks like it lists one contact name for one background photo.

I wish to post the screenshot here but my reputation is too low. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: And what is exactly your problem?

Comment: Not a clear question please specify what is your problem when displaying the ListView ... example: spacing,color,size ...etc

Comment: you have android:background="@drawable/bg" in your LinearLayout, what is its height ?

Comment: also you have android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" , make sure its size

Comment: i think the height of the `android:background="@drawable/bg"` is high,so only you get the long space between each contact name.

Comment: The screenshot looks like it lists one contact name for one background image. At the end of one background image, there is another background image and one contact name on it. Please comment here if you have any questions about my problem and please dont vote my question down.

Comment: I think Yugesh is right, setting height as wrap_content and having a large image as background could cause size issues.

Comment: I tried to set the background to color and from the result, I could see that the image has become the background for the text, not the background of the whole screen.

Comment: @user3014015 now you get the list rows correctly.

Comment: yes. I get the list rows correctly with the background of each list in color. I change android:background="@drawable/bg" to android:background="#99FF0000".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all items with same background set `@drawable/bg` as the background of list view instead of one item of list view.

Try this:

You can post the layout that has a listview, but for now consider this list view which has  `android:background="@drawable/bg"`

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">
</ListView>
```

And layout for each item will not have any background

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/contactTextView" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That is what I wish to do. Can you tell me how to make it? I appreciate your answer.